# Programa para convertir números binarios en decimales

Tags: javascript

Soy totalmente nuevo en este mundillo de la programación, y me he metido con JavaScript.

Estoy realizando (o intentándolo) unos ejercicios para ir pillando el lenguaje de programación, pero se me está atragantando bastante, principalmente porque todo lo estoy mirando por mi cuenta.
En un ejercicio de pasar números binarios a decimales, he econtrado un programa ya resuelto, pero no consigo entender cómo el programa funciona. 
A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Muchas gracias y un saludo,

```js
function binTodecimal(binstr){
  return binstr.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x, y, i){
      return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: va recorriendo de derecha a izquierda el binario y sumando las potencias de 2

Comment: Pues usa [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt#Ejemplos) recibe un parámetro opcional en este caso usa el número base 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te explico, la función recibe un string 'binstr', posteriormente crea un arreglo aplicando 'split' sobre el parámetro, en este caso el separador es cada digito del string.

Lo siguiente que hace es invertir el arreglo obtenido para simular lectura de derecha a izquierda, ya que así se hace la conversión a lápiz y papel, con 'reverse'.

Con 'reduce' empieza a extraer cada elemento del arreglo, además le pasa una función como parámetro, esta función debe tener parámetros:

- Total
- Valor extraído
- Índice del elemento extraído, opcional.
- Arreglo al que pertenece el item extraído, opcional.

En este caso solo ocupas los primeros 3 'function(x, y, i)' e indicar el índice desde donde iterar, que es cero.

Repasando, 'x' será total, 'y' el elemento extraído, 'i' su índice:

```
return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
```

Esa línea literalmente es igual a:

```
if(y==='1') //El elemento extraído es un "1"
    return x + Math.pow(2, i);//2 elevado a i
else //El elemento extraído es un "0"
    return x;
```

Al final x devolverá el valor en decimal.

Espero haberme expresado correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Mas o menos el flow del código es este:

```js
//function binTodecimal(binstr){

binstr = '101011'; // 32 * 1 + 16 * 0 + 8 * 1 + 4 * 0 + 2 * 1 + 1 * 1 = 43
console.log(binstr, '=', parseInt(binstr, 2));

//  return binstr
//  .split('')
console.log('split: ', binstr.split(''));
//  .reverse()
console.log('reverse: ', binstr.split('').reverse());
console.log('reduce: ');
binstr.split('').reverse().reduce(function(x, y, i) {
  console.log(
    ' +', Math.pow(2, i), '*', y, ' = ',
    (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x
  );
  return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
}, 0); // empieza en 0

/*
.reduce(function(x, y, i){
      return (y === '1') ? x + Math.pow(2, i) : x;
    }, 0);
}
//*/
```